# Registration and grading: OneNote vs Google Drive for classroom management

Tags: cloud

Original question:

I wonder if the two services are comparable? If you are familiar with both, how do you compare and contrast their capabilities as far as classroom management is concerned? My application would be to university math courses, including some Matlab programming. I have tried Google Drive in a limited fashion so far.

Edit:

My specific concerns are:

(1) Ease in creating student folders. What are steps for creating say 30 folders in each of theses services. As far as I know, in Google Drive, I have to make them manually one-by-one. Also, it looked as though students had to have a google account for the invitation to my drive to work.

(2) Having a grade book. Does either of the services help with maintaining a grading system? As far as know there is no built-in mechanism in Google Drive.

Comment: Well if you are going to work on collaborative projects i would recommend google drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work at a high school and we just made the choice between Microsoft and Google and went with Google.  The main reason was the classroom management that Google now offers, if you have a Google Apps for Education Account.

[Google Classroom](https://classroom.google.com)

It integrates with Google Drive seamlessly, and works really well on any device.  If you are running Chrome as well you can work on files offline.  Google Docs also has built in equation building tools.

Also a major selling feature is that Education institutions get Google Apps accounts for **free with unlimited cloud storage.**

My department (IT) uses OneNote to keep track of some of our notes and some project info.  I personally think the Google suite is better for classrooms than Microsoft.

I would also look at what devices you are going to be using and try each product out on them to see if they suit your needs.  For instance, some of the Google Apps on iPads have less features than through a web browser.  We keep out OneNote files on a local server instead of in the cloud and this limits where it can be synced to, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I have used both over the past 10 years.  OneNote -- without question.  Especially for mathematics if you have access to a pen-based tablet like the Surface, say.  The benefit of being able to write mathematics free-form and have it instantly shared with students is an incredible convenience.  Especially if you have access to the Class Notebook through Office365.  And, if you're using the ClassNotebook, your students can't change your materials but can pull it into their OneNote "space" and edit/add content.
OneNote is also not wifi-dependent ... you and students can develop content in the OneNote notebook and have it sync'ed automatically once you get wifi.  You can see classroom examples (not all math) here: http://bit.ly/onenotesamples and a developing history of OneNote Class Notebook in education over the past four years http://continuousformation.blogspot.ca

(fair admission of bias: we developed the model for the OneNote Class Notebook)